# Calculating the self resonance frequency of coil

Tags: inductor, resonance

If I have a coil of diameter D (in mm), using wire that is d mm in diameter, having N turns over a total height of L mm, assuming that it is just a single layer, and has an air core, is it possible to calculate what the self resonance frequency should be (approximately) of such a coil?  If so, what would the formula for the frequency be?  If not, what additional information needs to be known?

To dispel any concerns about doing someone's homework for them in advance, be assured that this is not a homework question.  I'm just curious how this kind of thing can be calculated.  Thanks.

So... for clarification purposes I have the following parameters:

```
1) Diameter of the coil (D) in mm
2) Diameter of the wire (d) in mm
3) Overall height of the coil (L) in mm
4) Number of turns (N)
```

I also know the material in the conductor of the wire, although I do not think that would be relevant to solving the problem unless the material was not a good conductor.

One thing we categorically cannot assume is that I will have any way to measure any properties of the coil with tools such as a meter or scope... I am asking how to calculate this on paper only.

Comment: The short answer is yes. First you calculate the self inductance which is dependent on the physical parameters as you just described. Then there will be a self resistance too which is basically the resistance of the wire. Then there is all the stray capacitance because of the coil turns and the dielectric used as insulation. Put it all together and you have a LRC circuit model of one component!  Resonance will be \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ or something like that. Forgive me its early! Its not trival though to calculate because the capacitance is hard to measure let alone calculate.

Comment: Single layer air-core coil, sounds like a Tesla coil secondary. Look for online calculators (javatc) for resonant frequency, and then have a look at the equations they use, and dig into the references they quote. In the limit, you can break the coil down into elements of wire and simulate the whole thing, but that's intractable. So approximations have been created (for example by Wheeler) over the decades that approximate, within certain ranges of width/height, what the inductance and capacitance is for a given geometry and number of turns. Whether application of that formula is calculating???

Comment: Do you know of any online calculators for resonant frequency from the parameters I have?  The only ones I've found require both inductance and capacitance as input.

Comment: Sorry resonance happens when \$ X_{L} = X_{C}\$ which is when \$ f_{r} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}} \$

Comment: http://i43.photobucket.com/albums/e358/gary350/003_zpszmidnli2.jpg. This is 89kHz 500W coil FYI

Comment: @Neil_UK I've now summarized the paramaters above, although I'm unsure why you thought I hadn't given you everything I know.  I was asking if there's anything else that I'd need not because I knew anything else, but because if this is actually not enough, I'd need to also figure out how to get that information, and knowing what information I actually need would be crucial to getting it.

Comment: @Mark There are online calculators, like JavaTC http://www.hvtesla.com/design-2.html (and google will give you others) that will do the sums for you, from your numerical inputs. You will be able to find standalone formulae, like Wheelers, http://home.earthlink.net/~jimlux/hv/wheeler.htm which will give you inductance, and others for capacitance (less easy to find) of coils, from which you can do the sums. A single equation accepting all the parameters? Well, you can be the first to develop and publicise! Play with JavaTC first before you do any other work on the issue.

Comment: @Mark you could look at this http://www.g3ynh.info/zdocs/magnetics/appendix/self_res/self-res.pdf for capacitance and self-resonance. Be warned that the lambda/4 length is hogwash, which doesn't invalidate the rest of the calculations. Why I didn't think you had given all the parameters is that even after I pointed you at Wheeler and JavaTC, you were still bleating that available formulae didn't work with your parameters. You've now clarified that you *do* have the parameters to use Wheeler (heigth, width, turns)

Comment: The website you mentioned for wheeler doesn't appear to load in my browser... are the formulas that it uses published anywhere else or used in another online calculator somewhere?  I'm reading through the pdf on self-resonance you mentioned by Knight now.  It's way more complicated that what I thought I needed to know.